# Dynamically Changing Images in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xamarin

Are there any way to have something similar to IOs scaling, where I only have to indicate the image size in the file's name? (e.g.: I have three images, img@1x.png, img@2x.png, img@3x.png and the application uses the best suitable for the ppi of the device)

Answer (score 0):

It is automatically supported, Xamarin.Forms is using the native image resources for each platform, the same way you would do natively.
In your case :

```
<Image Source="img.png"/>
```

and the platform will use the @x when it sees fit.

[more info in the Xamarin docs here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Native_Resolutions_Retina_and_High-DPI)

Comment: If I interpret it correctly, the docs are only talking about the IOS and android resolutions, but how can I achieve this on Windows? Will the windows platform use the @2 and @3 pictures, too?